# SQL COUNT column where value is greater than value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a basic select query that is looking at some sample data in my table. I am trying to get three pieces of information.

- Total Samples (total records)
- How many with a Score greater than or equal to 85
- How many with a Score less than 85

**Data:**

```
ScoreID RecordID    Score   ErrorMarkedToQID    ErrorActionID
1   2   30  Q00019  1
2   2   100 Q20039  3
3   3   30  Q10091  3
4   3   35  Q00019  5
6   4   5   Q10091  3
```

This is what I attempted:

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2018/09/12', @endDate DATE = '2018/09/24'

SELECT COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS totalSamples,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Score >= 85 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Score < 85 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
  FROM [SubmissionScores] AS s
  JOIN Submission AS sub
  ON sub.SubmissionID = s.RecordID
  WHERE sub.DateSubmittedUTC BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

My current output is that all fields are outputting 5 which is the total number of records. So it seems like my `CASE` logic isn't correct.

Can this be done in a simple query like I am attempting?

Comment: I think I just realized that those counts should really be `SUM()` :/
Sometimes it just needs to be written out for me to catch it apparently.

Comment: or `count(..)` with `else` excluded.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala Thanks! Didn't realize it could be done like that too. Is there a right vs wrong in this case using SUM vs COUNT ?

Comment: @SBB You've rediscovered the [rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)! Go forth and `sum`.

Comment: @SBB If this was a PEBKAC, post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2018/09/12', @endDate DATE = '2018/09/24'

SELECT COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS totalSamples,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Score >= 85 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Pass,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN s.Score < 85 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Fail
  FROM [SubmissionScores] AS s
  JOIN Submission AS sub
  ON sub.SubmissionID = s.RecordID
  WHERE sub.DateSubmittedUTC BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The Count() function will return the number of rows that match a specified criteria, but your Case() has a result for both match and no match, so it returns the same (total) number of rows in all case 
with Case() 0 or 1 you can use sum() which will summarize the result of the case

```
 DECLARE @startDate DATE = '2018/09/12', @endDate DATE = '2018/09/24'

SELECT COUNT(s.ScoreID) AS totalSamples,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Score >= 85 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
       SUM(CASE WHEN s.Score < 85 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
  FROM [SubmissionScores] AS s
  JOIN Submission AS sub
  ON sub.SubmissionID = s.RecordID
  WHERE sub.DateSubmittedUTC BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```